# why hana's is_valid_t SFINAE test use std::declval<F&&>() not use std::declval<F>()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

here is hana is_void impl code:

```
 namespace type_detail {
        template <typename F, typename ...Args, typename = decltype(
            std::declval<F&&>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...)
        )>
        constexpr auto is_valid_impl(int) { return hana::true_c; }

        template <typename F, typename ...Args>
        constexpr auto is_valid_impl(...) { return hana::false_c; }

        template <typename F>
        struct is_valid_fun {
            template <typename ...Args>
            constexpr auto operator()(Args&& ...) const
            { return is_valid_impl<F, Args&&...>(int{}); }
        };
    }

    //! @cond
    template <typename F>
    constexpr auto is_valid_t::operator()(F&&) const
    { return type_detail::is_valid_fun<F&&>{}; }
```

since  is_void_t accept F&&,`type_detail::is_valid_fun<F&&>` then  is_valid_fun's template arg is F&&,then  is_valid_impl's template  arg is F&&

...so why use `std::declval<F&&>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...)` not just use `std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)`?

Comment: Possibly because you can't instantiate a function. If `declval<T>` is implemented by the trick of calling a function (that's never implemented) returning `T`,  then would fail for `T` a function type: function types as formal arguments are decayed to pointers, but I don't think that happens for a return type. Btw. I see no `is_void` in this code?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `declval<T>()` returns `add_rvalue_reference_t<T>`.

Comment: @T.C.: Yes I know. Probably for the same reason. Oh, sorry, I'm stupid: even for a DIY `declval` it needs not be defined. Thanks.

Comment: It's at times like these that I wish I could agree with the general SO convention of altering history. :(

Comment: This is just overflowing with `&&`, probably a stylistic issue (when passing this stuff around, there are cases where you have to add `&&` for correctness, so it's perhaps easier to just add them all the time). Here we have `is_valid_impl` only ever instantiated with reference-typed `F` and `Args`, and then it adds an extra serving of `&&` on top just for fun. AFAICT, you can take out every instance of `&&` in every *template-argument-list* in this code, and it would still be correct.

Comment: @t.c. well almost in pathological: someone could pass an explicit F into is valid t operator().  I suspect the rigbt type would screw something up?  Or would decay cover it?  Or maybe gigo.  Really that one `&&` outside details is enough?

Comment: @Yakk Decay? What decay? (Note I said *template-argument-list*, not every instance of `&&` in the code.)